# How to script an Interval in Photoshop

Tags: photoshop, photoshop-script

I am trying to script something in Photoshop that has to run every X seconds. In JavaScript it would look like this:

```
function run() {
    alert('Ran!')
}
setInterval(run, 1000)
```

But in Photoshop's JavaScript, "setInterval is not a function". Any idea how else I would get any form of interval working?

Comment: This is a gooooood question. The only thing I've managed to do is either set a large loop & some calculations or another loop and check the time elapsed. - Though most would say that's memory hungry.- But hey! it's Photoshop!

Comment: Would you mind posting a simple example of this? I don't exactly understand how you did it.

Comment: Photoshop scripts don’t support timers and they block the host app. You’ll need a panel (cep) or plug-in (uxp) for that

Answer (score 1):

This is by no means a good example, however, it stalls for a second. Those that don't know it there's no pause or sleep function in ECMA 3. I don't use a while loop as that's asking for trouble in Photoshop and may lock things up - which may lose your work.

```
sleepy(1000)

function sleepy(milliseconds)
{
  // Start the fans please! I mean timer
  var dStart = new Date().getTime();

  var longtime = 10000000;
  for(var i = 0 ; i < longtime; i++)
  {
    var now = new Date().getTime();
    if (now > dStart + milliseconds)
      {
        // Stop the fans!
        var dEnd = new Date().getTime();
        var timeTaken = (dEnd - dStart)/1000;
        var msgTime = (timeTaken + " seconds.");
        alert(msgTime);
        // alert("Ran");
        return;
      }
  }
}
```

or if it's just a second, just calculate the Fibbonaci sequence to 28 spots. It's also machine dependant (and rather slower than expected in Photoshop)

```
function fibonacci(n)
{
  if (n < 2)
    return n
  else
  {
    return fibonacci(n-1) + fibonacci(n-2);
  }
}

var numOfNums = 28; // 0.91 seconds
// var numOfNums = 29; // 1.47 seconds
// var numOfNums = 30; // 2.39 seconds
// var numOfNums = 31; // 3.8  seconds

var dStart = new Date().getTime();
var msg = "";
for(var i = 0 ; i < numOfNums; i++)
{
  msg += fibonacci(i) + ", ";
}
var dEnd = new Date().getTime();
var timeTaken = (dEnd - dStart)/1000;

// alert(msg);
alert(timeTaken);
```

Comment: As epic as this is, it still locks up the UI. So I can't loop this to happen every 30s or so. I need something sort of async, so that the user can continue working while this triggers every 30s or whatever.

Comment: Sadly, you'll need to do that another way. See Sergey's comments above